# GDB: Referencing memory and the use of the '$' and '*' symbols

Tags: gdb

Just a quick question from me.

Whilst using GDB I have noticed that, when examining memory, the symbols '*' and '$' can be used to somehow dereference memory locations, define the value as a literal numeric value (rather than an address), or something similar.

I was wondering if anyone could clearly summarise how using these symbols effects what memory you are trying to access?

I am mid-way through writing a short tutorial on basic GDB usage and I could use a succinct definition of how these symbols are actually acting. Although I use them frequently when I use GDB, It dawned on me that I have not got a definition for what they are actually doing. If you have specific references to where this is discussed in GDB's [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) that would be most useful indeed. However, I have been unsuccessful (read impatient :P) in finding this information.

Thanks in advance,

A

Comment: From my little background research I have done since posting this question it seems the '$' symbol is used to indicate a variable, the same as in bash. The '*' seems to be used in a similar way to the C programming language and seems to dereference the data pointed to by the given address (as is done with pointers in C). Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The '$' symbol for variables and registers is described in https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html and https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html

Comment: Thank you. Infact, that was where I saw the information I was referring to in the previous comment. Your links are none the less useful :).